# PHP upload_max_filesize limit

Tags: php

It seems that in PHP, the value of post_max_size and upload_max_filesize cannot exceed 2GB on 32 bit systems as mentioned here - http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size
However, I have a 64-bit system and I still cannot set post values about 2gb. If I do so, PHP will not handle any post data, even if its just a few kb. Does anyone know how to make PHP handle larger amounts of POST data?

Comment: Is PHP compiled as a 64bit app? Running a 32bit PHP on a 64bit system doesn't make it magically able to handle >2gig files. 32bit apps CAN handle >2gig files if they're explicitly compiled with glibc's large file extensions.

Comment: I investigated this kind of issue a while back on a project at work where users upload DVD images to a system to later be burned to physical discs. The difficulty isn't necessarily in the file size limitation; you'll also run into plenty of weird timeout edge cases (it generally takes a *long* time to upload > 2 GB of data). My solution was to write a Java applet (yuck, I know) to chunk the large files into smaller pieces. Those pieces then get uploaded, and reassembled on the server. There's a lot less headache down that road, in my opinion.

Comment: I agree with @Jonah. While you may be able to get PHP to do this, uploading 2GB+ through a regular HTTP request (maybe even through the browser?) does not seem to be very reliable. Yes, theoretically it should work, but in practice it is rarely used and you'll find all the limitations in all the involved pieces. Is there no way for you to use FTP or other protocols specialized for large file transfers?

Comment: @Marc B: How do you compile PHP as a 64bit app? Doesn't it automatically do this on a 64bit system?

Comment: @Jonah Bishop: I definitely don't want to use a java applet.

Comment: @deceze: I suppose ftp would be the easiest solution, but it makes processing the file harder.

Comment: PHP_INT_MAX is 2^63-1, which is the limit for a 64-bit signed integer. Doesn't this mean that PHP should handle 64-bit integers in the configuration files?

Answer (score 0):

post_max_size to 2GB? interesting. I would use chunks of 2MB.

Comment: Why would you not advise post_max_size as 2GB?

Comment: For the same reasons I mentioned in my comment above: you'll likely run into timeout problems, you may run into out-of-memory problems, you don't get retries if the upload fails halfway through (this can easily be implemented when you chunk the files), modern browsers typically don't allow native uploads of more than 2 GB, etc. Trust me, this problem is a pain to work around. Chunking via an applet or perhaps a flash plugin are your only realistic options (that I'm aware of) outside of FTP.

Comment: what happens if 1000 people or more upload at the same time? you will need huge memory not mentionning timeout issues. What if you want to increase to 4GB?. If you want to transfer 2GB without problems, use chunks same way as if you download 2GB file from internet, they don't give you a 2GB response, they chunk the file take a look at Transfer-Encoding: chunked.

Answer (score 0):

you can change limitation from apache server,
for manual: [apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody)
It seems this limitation on 2Gb can be greater on 64bits installations, maybe. And i'm not sure setting 0 in this directove does not reach the compilation limit. see for examples that thread:
[apache large file support](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1385890.html)
and also alter the max_input_time in PHP.